# Plotting a route using Kendo UI Map widget and OpenStreetMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, openstreetmap, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-map

Is there any way to plot a route using Kendo UI Map widget and OpenStreetMap with a series of latitude-longitude pairs which represent points along the route?
My understanding is that it is probably possible with Bing and Google Maps APIs (references: http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo31; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e754aa6-d067-4e0e-9872-721fb056e60e/how-to-draw-the-route-path-in-bing-map-version-70-by-passing-the-lat-and-long-as-a-source-and?forum=bingmapsajax), which require purchase of corresponding API keys. I am looking for an alternate approach, with possibly some hard work involved. I am open to suggestions with alternatives to OpenStreetMap and Kendo UI as well.

Any direction in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look into the services using OSM data: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: @Karussell: I'll have a look. Appreciate your input.